# Parsing Array to only display String PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have an array within an array within an array and so on:

```
array(3) {
    [0]=> array(1) {
        ["weather"]=> array(2) {
            ["ID"]=> string(1) "1"
            ["weather_types"]=> string(5) "Clear"
        }
    }
    [1]=> array(1) {
        ["weather"]=> array(2) {
            ["ID"]=> string(1) "2"
            ["weather_types"]=> string(6) "Clouds"
        }
    }
    [2]=> array(1) {
        ["weather"]=> array(2) {
            ["ID"]=> string(1) "3"
            ["weather_types"]=> string(4) "Rain"
        }
    }
}
```

I will assign as a variable, let's use:
$select_item

and then have the weather_types strings, "Clear", "Cloudy", and "Rain" w/o quotes be the only data that appears in my select/option list.

I need to somehow remove all the other array data so that "Clear", "Cloudy", and "Rain" is left.

then I will save the selected option to the database table.

Comment: also will use foreach loop to populate the select option list.

Comment: and what did you tried? Looks like you want to somebody did this work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `$weather` is the array and you want the `value` attribute to contain `ID`. Either way, adjusting the following to your needs should be trivial.

```
foreach ($weather as $select_item) {
  echo '<option value="', $select_item['weather']['ID'], '">', $select_item['weather']['weather_types'], '</option>';
}
```